# PydanticUserError: A non-annotated attribute was detected in Airflow db init command

Tags: python, airflow, virtualenv, pydantic

I'm trying to run the `airflow db init` command in my Airflow project, but I'm encountering the following error:

```
(venv) ➜  aflow airflow standalone

/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:261 UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'orm_mode' has been renamed to 'from_attributes'
/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_config.py:261 UserWarning: Valid config keys have changed in V2:
* 'orm_mode' has been renamed to 'from_attributes'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/bin/airflow", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/__main__.py", line 48, in main
    args.func(args)
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_config.py", line 51, in command
    func = import_string(import_path)
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/utils/module_loading.py", line 36, in import_string
    module = import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 883, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/standalone_command.py", line 35, in <module>
    from airflow.jobs.scheduler_job_runner import SchedulerJobRunner
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job_runner.py", line 58, in <module>
    from airflow.models.serialized_dag import SerializedDagModel
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/models/serialized_dag.py", line 34, in <module>
    from airflow.serialization.serialized_objects import DagDependency, SerializedDAG
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/serialization/serialized_objects.py", line 57, in <module>
    from airflow.serialization.pydantic.dag_run import DagRunPydantic
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/serialization/pydantic/dag_run.py", line 24, in <module>
    from airflow.serialization.pydantic.dataset import DatasetEventPydantic
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/airflow/serialization/pydantic/dataset.py", line 40, in <module>
    class TaskOutletDatasetReferencePydantic(BaseModelPydantic):
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 95, in __new__
    private_attributes = inspect_namespace(
  File "/home/ugur/aflow/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pydantic/_internal/_model_construction.py", line 328, in inspect_namespace
    raise PydanticUserError(
pydantic.errors.PydanticUserError: A non-annotated attribute was detected: `dag_id = <class 'str'>`. All model fields require a type annotation; if `dag_id` is not meant to be a field, you may be able to resolve this error by annotating it as a `ClassVar` or updating `model_config['ignored_types']`.

For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.0.2/u/model-field-missing-annotation
```

How can I resolve this issue?

python --version:
Python 3.10.12
airflow version:
2.6.2

Answer (score 4):

airflow 2.6.2 has `pydantic>=1.10.0` as a dependency see https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2.6.2/setup.cfg#L127
and pydantic has a new major release 2.0.0 recently because of that it is broken you can track the Github issue https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/32311.
meanwhile, you can restrict pydantic version `pydantic>=1.10.0,<2.0.0` see https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/2811ba710991d71466afa21c500ee55aeda5d8a1/setup.cfg#L131

Comment: Hello @Pankaj Singh, How should I restrict pydantic version. In which file I need to perform the above changes?

Answer (score 0):

uninstall pydantic, then using pip install pydantic==1.10.1 solved my issue